# Custom view handler argument to filter out child nodes

Tags: 8

I need to create a custom contextual filter in Drupal 8 to render all the child nodes of a Parent node inside the block view. The child node having an entity reference field.

E.g:

----------View Block--------------

Parent ID:

Child 1, Child 2 , Child 3....

Comment: Do you also have an actual question?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens is correct, this isn't Drupal Facts.

Comment: @NoSssweat ... good point, but wait a minute: It isn't Drupal *Questions* either, but Drupal *Answers*!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens true, but in order to get an answer, you need to ask a question.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens  Drupal 8 - List all child nodes inside a view block based on its Parent ID. Basically need to form a group containing referenced child nodes in a block